# 'Meaning of life' as per Viktor Frankl's Man's search for Meaning

Tags: reference-request, existentialism

I recently read 'Man's search for Meaning' by Viktor Frankl. It was a very moving book and in it the author describes three ways in which a man may find meaning in his life.
1.Through some creative act
2.Through an experience of beauty/art
3.Through suffering

Are there any other books that deal with the 'meaning of life' question in a positive way and are not too hard to understand? And also, I am looking to gain some understanding what are some other ways a man may search for meaning except the three ways stated in the book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend this [video course](http://www.thegreatcourses.com/tgc/courses/course_detail.aspx?cid=4320) on "The Meaning of Life" by Jay Garfield.

It is an excellent overview of the subject, and follows the topic through the full scope of Western and Eastern philosophy.  (I studied with Jay a few decades ago, and he's a wonderful teacher, as well as an impressive scholar.)

Answer (score 2):

You might really like the works of Gerald May, especially "The Awakened Heart," "Addiction and Grace,"  and "Wisdom of Wilderness."  May was a practicing psychiatrist for a number of years but had questions that the scientific method would not penetrate for him, so he studied spirituality.  He later joined the staff of Shalem Institute which teaches spiritual direction, among other things.  He's much in line with Frankl's fundamental thought, but he does expand into other areas than Frank's 'big 3.' I have found reading May a help in opening up my own search.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend,

> ***The Four Agreements***

by don Miguel Ruiz. This a top seller. Very easy to understand it gives you practical examples. The Four Agreements gives you a practical guide to personal freedom. The philosophy he teaches is known as the Toltec Wisdom.

[http://www.amazon.com/The-Four-Agreements-Practical-Personal/dp/1878424319/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_b](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1878424319)

I also suggest Deepak Chopra's

> ***The Ultimate Happiness Prescription***

Your situations reminds me of myself a few years ago. A friend gave me

> ***"Man's search for Ultimate Meaning"***

. It is difficult to understand. It seems like it was written in a research/ essay form.

***I recommend you first read self help books.*** These type of books gives you a direct approach which you can apply to your life right away. ***It takes philosophy and derives it into wisdom. Wisdom is what you already know and you are being reminded of***.

Here is a list of top sellers

http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_1?rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A4736%2Cn%3A4739&bbn=4736&ie=UTF8&qid=1342128553

Best wishes